# Maximal Ideal in Polynomial Ring of DVR

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be a discrete valuation ring with uniformizing parameter $t\neq 0$. Show that the ideal generated by $tT-1$ is maximal in $\mathcal{O}_K[T]$.

I have tried explicitly computing the quotient, since you can write every element in $\mathcal{O}_K[T]$ as a polynomial of the form $\sum_{i=0}^n a_it^{k_i}T^i$ for units $a_i$, and use the relation $tT=1$, but that doesn't seem to be getting me anywhere.

Comment: Well, as you noticed, the quotient is a ring in which T has an inverse. In fact, that quotient is isomorphic to the localization of the ring at t. Can you show this is a field?

Comment: Oh! I can just construct a ring isomorphism between the quotient and the localization of the DVR.

Thanks!

Comment: To show that the ideal is maximal, you have then to show that that localization is a field.

Comment: So you are trying to prove that this principal ideal is of height two?

Comment: The ring $\mathcal{O}_K/(tT-1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_{K,t}$. This is the ring $\mathcal{O}_K$ but with $t$ inverted. In a DVR, inverting the uniformizer gives you the fraction field.